# How to display and work with strange characters in R

Tags: r, gsub, decoding

I have a data set in R in which some variables contains strings with "strange" characters, such as ë, é or €. Unfortunately, the source of the data set itself has some errors in displaying these characters originated from the export. For example: `â‚¬` is displayed in the string, which should be `€`

I've managed to debug these using a list provided on https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html. Despite my code being a little redundant, I've managed to solve the problem. For each strange character I used `gsub` to revalue for the character that it should be. I think (actually, I know) that this could be coded more efficient, but hey, it worked for me. Here's what I did:

`df$var1 <- gsub("â‚¬", "€", df$var1)`

However, after saving my code and reopening the code, it is not working anymore. I think I saved it in the wrong coding format, causing some information to get lost. My question is if it is possible to get the code working again. R is displaying parts of my original code in red font with a red background. It would be a pain to retype my code, so I hope there's a quick fix for this.

By the way: there's no option to rerun the export with different settings, so I'd like to fix the problem at hand with the data set at hand. I've tried all the encodings which R shows when you press "save with encoding". For example, UTF-8 correctly works with ë and ë, but not with €

Comment: Is it a question of encoding? Did you try `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", 'en_GB.UTF-8')`?

Comment: Then I receive the following error: Warning message: ```In Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_GB.UTF-8") : OS reports request to set locale to "en_GB.UTF-8" cannot be honored```